# Enforcing Blazor webassembly to use Newtonsoft.Json on client side

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

In Blazor webassembly is there a way to enforce the use of Newtonsoft.Json serlialization for httpclient and methods such as GetJsonAsync, PostAsJsonAsync etc.

Or the only way is to write helper methods and use GetAsync and then serialize the response manually using Newtonsoft.Json?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is there a way to enforce the use of Newtonsoft.Json  for ... PostAsJsonAsync etc.

No. This has been shifting around a bit lately, especially for Blazor. But the System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions are now directly dependent on System.Text.Json, not pluggable.

So yes, you will have to write your own helpers, not too big a deal. The linker might even remove the System.Text.Json classes in a Release build, I'm not sure.

But the counter question is of course why you need this?  NewtonSoft is legacy from now on and if you really have incompatible data maybe ask if you can resolve this with some System.Text options.

Comment: Well the use of attributes such as [JsonProperty("model")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] was being very usefull to me. I didnt know there was an alternative, but after your answer you made me think. I have found the following link  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/ It looks like there is a proper alternative

Comment: The problem is System.Text.Json is still largely a burning trash fire.  It doesn't support language specific things like TypeConverters.  That should have been baked in long before they even got started let alone rolled out a released product.

Comment: I now stepped into the problem, that System.Text.Json does not support the `[JsonConstructor]` attribute. So now I have to equip all my DTOs with public setters. Yeah sure, I can do that, but that would break the expected immutability of DTOs. And I will certainly not write my own parser as officially suggested here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#specify-constructor-to-use).

Comment: Also unless I'm mistaken System.Text.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute isn't available for .Net Standard 2.1. The only JsonIgnoreAttribute that I can seem to reference in my Blazor app is the Newtonsoft one, and System.Text.Json / System.Net.Http.Json ignores that attribute so I currently have no way to exclude a property from serialisation. I'm working around it by making the property protected and rewriting calling code to go via an intermediary which is obviously a whole lot of fun.

Comment: NewtonSoft does still have some advantages - In my case I wanted to deserialize to `Dictionary<string, object>` in order to create an `ExpandoObject`. `System.Text.Json` deserialized to `JsonElement` whereas Json.Net deserialized to anonymous, which is what I wanted.

Comment: Legacy? It still has 728K downloads a day! Lol

Comment: Where do you get that Newtonsoft is legacy?

Answer (score 2):

I struggled for a while to move from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json, mainly because of a few edge cases and a reliance on TypeNameHandling.  Blazor WebAssembly finally gave me the incentive to rearchitect those dependencies away.

Here are some interesting stats on the effect of bundling NewtonSoft.Json with a stock Blazor WebAssembly App:

Blazor WebAssembly App (.NET 7.0)

- AOT on:   26.5 MB
- AOT off:  15.2 MB

Blazor WebAssembly App (.NET 7.0) + Newtonsoft.Json (13.0.2)

- AOT on: 56.6 MB
- AOT off: 22.4 MB

These are the published file sizes, with no attempt to trim or compress.